# Python - converting bitmap image to list of colors per pixel

Tags: python, python-3.x, bitmap

I have a functioning code for bitmaps up to 22 by 22 pixels, however any more than that weird things happen, anyone have any idea why?
the program is to be used to automate building of large structures in minecraft/possibly other 'pixel-based' games. the current state is working up to 22by22pixels, but no more, and I wonder why/how to fix it.

Current error message(for images over 22 pixels): 
    KeyError (while searching palette, reason: color is no longer a tuple of rgb, but a single digit for unknown reason

desired size is up to 128 by 128, result is (for a 2 by 1 bitmap) -simplified as it may have to be a square:
[(0,0, '0-0-0', black), (0,1, '255, 255, 255', white)]

Current program:

```
# palette.py
# Palette with rgb-values depicting different blocks in-game:
predef = {}         #initialize a list variable, the fill it:
predef['255-255-255'] = 'air'
predef['255---0---0'] = 'redstone_block'
predef['--0--38-255'] = 'lapis_block'
predef['0-0-0'] = 'coal_block'

# main.py
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import json
import palette

def convert(filein, pal = palette.predef, zz = 0):
    '''
    due to a combined internal/external palette system ignore the warnings about incoherent types of str and dict
    as the dict is the internal, and the str is the filename of a json containing a dict.

    :param filein: Filename of bitmap
    :param pal: blank to use internal, or specify a separate palette.json
    :return:
    '''
    customset = []                  # customset list for blocks and positions

    if pal is not palette.predef:
        with open(pal) as js:
            pal = json.load(js)
        #print(pal) #debug to check palette

    im = Image.open(str(filein))
    p = np.array(im) #.reshape(-1, 3)
    print('width/height:', len(p), 'by', len(p))
    for y in range(0, len(p)):
        for x in range(0, len(p)):
            pix = p[y][x]
            pix = str(pix).replace(' ', '-').replace('[', '').replace(']', '')
            print(pix)
            pixcolor = (y, x, pix, pal[pix])     # Switch comment statu on these to see the error
            #pixcolor = pix                      # instead of the error message

            customset.append(pixcolor)

    return customset

print(convert('./1.bmp', './palettetest.json') # works with a bitmap up to 22 by 22
```

Comment: the zz in the function of convert() is not implemented yet, but is supposed to be the starting point at z=? for building.  There are also just a few colors implemented, they are in the palette.py file as rgb values

Answer (score 0):

found a solution:

from PIL import Image
    import numpy as np
    import json
    import time
    import palette             # Why is this needed when we have --0---0---0 above?? -unknown

```
def convert(filein, pal = palette.predef, zz = 0):
    '''
    due to a combined internal/external palette system ignore the warnings about incoherent types of str and dict
    as the dict is the internal, and the str is the filename of a json containing a dict.

    :param filein: Filename of bitmap
    :param pal: blank to use internal, or specify a separate palette.json
    :return:
    '''
    customset = []                  # customset list for blocks and positions
    if pal is not palette.predef:
        with open(pal) as js:
            pal = json.load(js)
        #print(pal)

    photo = Image.open(filein)  # opens the image
    photo = photo.convert('RGB')

    width = photo.size[0]
    height = photo.size[1]
    print('Size of current image is: {} by {}\n'.format(width, height))
    for y in range(0, height):
        row = ''

        for x in range(0, width):
            RGB = photo.getpixel((x,y))     # Gets the color value of pixel in color rgb
            R, G, B = RGB                   # Splits the rgb values
            rgb= str(RGB).replace(', ','-').replace('(', '').replace(')', '')
            info = 'x: {}, y: {} - pixelcolor: {}, block: {}'.format(x, y, rgb, pal[rgb])
            time.sleep(0.01) # to releave the cpu a bit
            customset.append(info)
            #print(info)

    return customset

print(convert('./1.bmp'))
```

Comment: Please add an answer if there is a better solution to the problem, and/or if you know **why** the first code gets corrupted with images above 22x22 pixels